# Add and Remove css while using slide toggle

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

How to add css 'display : inline' when use slide down and add css 'display : none' when use slide up?
I have using the following code.

```
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<span>';
                echo '<div id="paris" style="width:380px;">';
                echo translate('paris top');
                echo '<div style="display: none;">';
                echo translate('paris top second');
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<a href="#" class="readmore_paris">';
                echo "...See More";
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';

            $('.readmore_paris').click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $('#paris div').slideDown(function () {
                       $("#paris div").css({display: "inline"});
                 });
                 $('#paris div').slideUp(function () {
                       $("#paris div").css({display: "none"});
                 });
                  $(this).text( $(this).text() == '...See More' ? "Show Less" : "...See More");
             });
```

Comment: What is not working with the current code?

Comment: Display none is not working while slide up

Comment: Try slidetoggle as in my answer. I've allowed for making it inline instead of the default block

Comment: Please clarify, you don't want to hide it before sliding up. Or is that what you want, so that it disappears and what's below it moves up?

Comment: Or do you mean you need to it be inline WHILE it's animating? The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you're probably expecting.

```
$('.readmore_paris').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#paris div').slideToggle();
     $(this).text( $(this).text() == '...See More' ? "Show Less" : "...See More");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6X6/

If you need the div to be display:inline, not block

```
$('.readmore_paris').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#paris div').slideToggle(function () {
         if ($(this).is(':visible')){
             $(this).css({display: 'inline'});
         }
     });
     $(this).text( $(this).text() == '...See More' ? "Show Less" : "...See More");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6X6/2/

Comment: RE: `{display:` vs `{"display":`, the keys of objects can be encapsulated, it doesn't change the object, it's not a syntax error when they aren't. The only problem is when of the keys conflicts with something, e.g.  `{class: 'foo'}` breaks IE.

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
$("#paris div").toggle();
```

it will show and hide the element alternatively.....

Comment: Yes. But the second div is not in Inline. It toggle as separate div. So the unwanted space is displaying near the first div